# Trying to use C wrapper in Go?

Tags: c, go, leptonica

I must be missing something but I'm trying to use the Leptonica C library in Go using a C wrapper that was made for that purpose:

https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.leptonica/blob/master/leptonica.go

But I don't understand... it allows me to import files but then how do I actually invoke the Leptonica functions? (Specifically I want to detect the deskew of the image using Leptonica.)

I don't see any function in the Go wrapper that allows me to send a command like this. How do I talk to it?

Comment: It seems like this wrapper does not expose the complete API of leptonica. You might need to write your own. It isn't too difficult.

Comment: Well it must be something... if all it did was let you load images but do nothing with them then it would be useless for any purpose.

Comment: But a great place for you to start from. Its what pull requests were made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go.leptonica` simply hasn't implemented that. You'll have to call the C functions yourself.

Use `leptonica.go` as a starting point, and write your own wrapper.

Comment: I would *love* to be able to do that, think of all the C libraries I could use! Alas, I've never written C. Could you please point me in the right direction for how to do this?

Comment: That was surprisingly easy. Go makes me happy :)